# Consider bit array of size 8. What is the probability that number of consecutive ones is at most 2?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider bit array of size 8. What is the probability that number of consecutive ones is at most 2? Generalize to n bit array

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: So $01101101$ is allowed? it has two sets of consecutive $1$ but not string is more than $2$.  Or is that not allowed because there can only be one such set?

Comment: This string is allowed.

Comment: There are only 256 cases, just brute force it.

Comment: See here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288357/number-of-binary-arrays-of-length-n-with-k-consecutive-1s

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**General solution**

There are $2^n$ arrays. Let $X(n)$ be the number which have at most two consecutive $1$s.

For $n \ge 3$, the arrays which have at most two consecutive $1$s  start off with one of:-

$0$ or $10 $ or $110$.

Therefore $X(n)$=$X(n-1)+X(n-2)+X(n-3)$, where we take $X(0)=1$.

**The case $n=8$**

We have $X(0)=1,X(1)=2,X(2)=4$. Then applying the recurrence relation gives:

$X(3)=1+2+4=7$, $X(4)=2+4+7=13$, ... , $X(8)=149$.